# Change School year in a specific month vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a project which involves school enrollment. I managed to add a new school year everytime the year changes. but i can only manage to add it that way. I want to do is I want to change the school year in a specific month which is June. Can you help me to achieve this? I'm using vb 2012.

Btw i used this to add a year in the current year

```
     Dim nowYear As Integer = Date.Now.Year
    sy.Text = String.Format("{0}-{1}", nowYear, nowYear + 1)
```

THanks for the help.

Comment: Check if the current month (`Date.Now.Month`) is before or after June, if it is before June, use `nowYear - 1` and `nowYear` instead of `nowYear` and `nowYear + 1`

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. btw i used nowyear and nowyear +1 coz its a school year. I need the current and the next year, Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this way:

```
If DateTime.Now.Month = 6 Then
 nowYear = nowYear + 1
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the help mate.. appreciated it.